What does 丸めた here mean? (in describing how someone speaks)

彼特有の丸めた―目的を背後に隠して相手に好意を示す話し方は、めいは好きではない。

I don't quite get it.
"His characteristic... the way to show to the partner kindness while hiding his true motive. Mei didn't like it at all.

Is it a quote from a novel or something?

Yes, that is correct

First of all, 丸めた話し方 (literally "rounding way of speaking") is not a common phrase. You shouldn't regard it as a set phrase and use it elsewhere. My interpretation below is largely based on the accompanying explanation right after it (目的を背後に隠して相手に好意を示す), but you need to see the broader context, too.
I feel the following two definitions of 丸める are equally relevant:

丸める can mean "to round" as in "to round a fraction into the nearest integer".
丸める can also mean "to cajole; to seduce" (cf. 丸め込む).

So this 丸めた話し方 probably refers to intentionally omitting details and speaking in broad terms to avoid raising suspicion, to the point where it sounds somewhat cajoling. While 丸い話し方 may simply refer to a gentle way of speaking, describing his way of speaking as 丸めた話し方 may imply that she has found some sly intent in his speech.

It takes some leap to interpret it, and interpretations may differ. (I assume it is quoted from a novel or something where the author can be a bit creative.)
人柄が丸い means being nice and non-confrontational. By extention, 丸めた can be read as 'pretending to be nice'. It's not very idiomatic to describe a way of speaking like that, though, unlike 丸い which is commonly used figuratively.
The opposite of 丸い in this sense is 角がある - having tendency to cause friction (in relationships) or simply combative.
